# In RefreshScope, why should we add the processing logic of getClass() when receiving the ContextRefreshedEvent notification

Tags: spring-cloud

In org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope, the logic for processing the ContextRefreshedEvent notification is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        start(event);
    }

    public void start(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if (event.getApplicationContext() == this.context && this.eager
                && this.registry != null) {
            eagerlyInitialize();
        }
    }

    private void eagerlyInitialize() {
        for (String name : this.context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition definition = this.registry.getBeanDefinition(name);
            if (this.getName().equals(definition.getScope())
                    && !definition.isLazyInit()) {
                Object bean = this.context.getBean(name);
                                // question 1
                if (bean != null) {
                                     // question 2
                     bean.getClass();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Question 1: If the bean does not exist, an exception will be thrown when the getBean method is executed. Why do we need to judge whether the bean is null?

Question 2: It seems meaningless to execute bean.getClass(), but why do you do it？

I hope someone can answer the above two questions. Thanks.

Comment: For 1 it shouldn't throw because we just got all the bean definition names, so it exists and won't throw. For 2, I can't tell you why. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer could. This is where it was introduced https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/c28ca5de91408e6c64a2c9a3e1977b8f104940ac

Comment: For 1, if this bean exists, I think the result obtained through getBean is definitely not null. The process of judging whether it is not equal to null here is somewhat redundant.

Comment: I already know why it is necessary to judge whether the bean is null, and the details of the reason can be seen from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/297. And for the question 2, I have asked Mr. Dayer who said he can't remember why he added getClass(). And Probably it tweaks Spring to do some work to resolve the class. The code doesn’t look like that any more though.